# Why MongoDB can create unique index but Mongoid cannot?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

In the MongoDB shell, if I do the following, then an index is created, and also prevent duplicate records from being inserted:

```
db.analytics.ensureIndex({page: 1, some_id: 1, ga_date: -1}, {unique: true});
```

But I thought Mongoid can do the same:
http://mongoid.org/docs/indexing/

So I have:

```
class PageAnalytic < Analytic
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :page, :type => String
  field :some_id, :type => Integer
  field :ga_date, :type => Time
  field :pageviews, :type => Integer
  field :timeOnPage, :type => Integer
  index(
    [
      [ :page, Mongo::ASCENDING ],
      [ :some_id, Mongo::ASCENDING ],
      [ :ga_date, Mongo::DESCENDING ]
    ],
    :unique => true
  )
end
```

and do a

```
rake db:create_indexes
```

but still, duplicate records can be inserted?

**Update:** it is quite strange, but after I added the index in the MongoDB shell and dropping the collection, and then recreated the index either in the MongoDB Shell or Mongoid, now I can drop the collection in MongoDB shell, and then rake create the index, and use mongoid to add the same documents twice, and mongod will say error for duplicate key.

Comment: what version of mongoid are you using?

Answer (score 7):

Did you use the normal way to save your model? Like:

`page_analyitc.save`

If you use this way to save model, mongoid won't give any error message.(if there have a duplicate key on mongodb)

So the correct way to do this is using:

`page_analyitc.safely.save`

It will raise an error like:

> Mongo::OperationFailure: 11001: E11001
>   duplicate key on update

Hope these information can help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a `index` in your document, mongoid wont create any index automagically. In order to create the index, you need to run the rake task `rake db:mongoid:create_indexes` as you can see in the new docs http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/indexing.html .